# Преобразовать строки в числа в столбце DataFrame'а, избавившись от нецифровых символов

Tags: python, строки, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Имеется датафрейм df_compliance:

```
name                                pass_info

Иванов Петр Александрович       4 520 802 159
Петров Михаил Иванович          4501256807
Сидоров Дим Димыч               4308 506310
Куприн Салтык Алекс             4513 № 056779
Воркутов Михаил Петрович        4501152999
```

Требуется привести колонку pass_info в одинаковый вид, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
 name                                pass_info

Иванов Петр Александрович       4520802159
Петров Михаил Иванович          4501256807
Сидоров Дим Димыч               4308506310
Куприн Салтык Алекс             4513056779
Воркутов Михаил Петрович        4501152999
```

Помогите разобраться как это сделать...

пытаюсь это сделать через df_compliance['pass_info'].apply(' ',join), но получается ерунда :(

Comment: df_compliance['pass_info'] какого типа? и символ `№` внутри числа - это опечатка или намеренно поставленный?

Comment: я при открытии csv файла эти столбцы перевел к str, к сожалению, не опечатка, так заполняли "люди" :((((((

Comment: столбец 'pass_info' должен содержать только цифры?

Comment: да, только цифры без пробелов и других знаков

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) и [pd.to_numeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
In [14]: df['pass_info'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pass_info'].str.replace('\D', ''), errors='coerce')

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
                        name   pass_info
0  Иванов Петр Александрович  4520802159
1     Петров Михаил Иванович  4501256807
2          Сидоров Дим Димыч  4308506310
3        Куприн Салтык Алекс  4513056779
4   Воркутов Михаил Петрович  4501152999

In [16]: df.dtypes
Out[16]:
name         object
pass_info     int64    # <---- NOTE!
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

```
trim = lambda ss: ''.join(s for s in ss if s.isdigit())

df_compliance.pass_info.apply(trim)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с регулярками:

```
import re
trim = re.compile("\D").sub('', s)

df_compliance.pass_info.apply(trim)
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже очень неплохой вариант!

Comment: +1, так изящнее, чем в моём ответе.